# How to use hyphen in object property name?

Tags: javascript

`$('.class').data({data-toggle: "whatever-value", data-target: "#id"});`

I keep getting syntax errors for the `-`

I originally tried `.attr` then switched to `.data` because I thought that would fix it.

Can someone help with this easy problem?

Thanks

Comment: Read the updated title and tags. This is a *SyntaxError* which is not related to jQuery. (Switching from attr to data has some different implications as well.)

Comment: @user2864740 I titled it with "jQuery" as that is what most people would type in their question when looking for an answer to a similar problem. As I did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to set/update a `data-*` attribute, you need quotes if you set the attribute:

```
$('.class').attr({"data-toggle": "whatever-value", "data-target": "#id"});
```

Otherwise it parses it like

```
data-toggle
```

meaning

```
data - toggle
```

subtracting two variables.

You can also use `.data()` with

```
$('.class').data({"toggle": "whatever-value", "target": "#id"});
```

but that does not assign `data-*` attributes it just stores the data in jQuery's storage system.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be an easy fix. And thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to what's alredy been pointed out, in Javascript, objects have properties defined by arbitrary strings.

`obj.prop` is really just sugar for `obj["prop"]`, with the latter being more expressive because all characters are allowed in the latter. Likewise, `{prop: "val"}` is really sugar for `{"prop": "val"}`. This is just one of many cases where you'll have to resort to the desugared syntax.

Comment: Excellent explanation!