# Is there any way for my to change this from dataCy to data-cy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is some code on a page:

```
addAnother={{
          text: language('Add variant'),
          dataCy: 'addVariant',
          as: 'button',
          buttonProps: { variant: 'alternate', className: cx.addAnotherButton, onClick: () => setOpened(true) },
        }}
```

When this gets outputted on the page the attribute is dataCy, is there anything I can do to make it show up as data-cy?

Comment: Write it as `'data-cy'` in the code?

Comment: The key being the quotes around it.  Otherwise javascript thinks you are doing subtraction.

Comment: or [How to use hyphen in object property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876233/how-to-use-hyphen-in-object-property-name/22876258)